# como valido en javascript los campos vacios antes de enviar a mysql como hago para que al darle submit no se envie datos ya que me los envia vacios

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

este codigo es de javascrip cpn ajax mete los datos a mysql y php con ajax envia los datos para evitar recargar los datos pero cuando le doy enviar sin los campos llenos me envia los datos pero vacios y se va llenando de campos vacios

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function loadData(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'select-data.php',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data){
                    $("#content").html(data);
                }
            });
        }

        loadData();

        $("#btn").on("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var msg = $("#msg").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'insert-data.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {name: name, msg: msg},
                success: function(data){
                    if (data == 1) {
                        loadData();

                        alert('Comment Submitted Successfully.');
                        $("#form").trigger("reset");
                    }else {
                        alert("Comment Can't Submit.");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: pues por ejemplo ponle un `if (name == "" OR msg == "" ) { alert("¡Faltan datos!); } else { $.ajax({....... }` despues de la linea del `var msg`

Comment: Si tienes una etiqueta form con los inputs nombre y mensaje dentro, por ej, puedes ponerle el atributo required a los inputs, de esta manera obligara a usuario a llenarlos

Comment: Si los tiene cada uno required pero por alguna extraña razón no funcionan, sabes porque? Mientras tanto usare la validacion como la dice masterguru y les diré si funcionó por si alguien más tiene está pregunta en el futuro gracias amigos

Comment: Seguramente no te funcionan los required porque necesitas enviarlos con un form para ello, y en tu código tan solo recoges sus valores.  Para conseguir que funcionen debes usar un form, con un boton submit, y luego usar formData para pasarselos al ajax. Pero vamos, si son solo dos valores con el if de antes ya es suficiente.

Comment: gacias masterguru eso fue de gran ayuda, eso soluciono mi error todos los dias aprendemos algo nuevo